# How to make docker-compose django server run on local wifi network, so our iOS developer can test the API from the iPhone device?

Tags: android, django, docker, networking, docker-compose

I'm trying to serve django on our local wifi IP, so our client developer can use his iOS device to test the API. The problem is that when I run the containers, it's only accessible from my chrome browser as localhost(=chrome browser run on the same macbook that is used to run the containers)

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  dev_postgres_data: {}
  dev_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/dev/django/Dockerfile
    image: apps_dev_django
    container_name: django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.dev/.django
      - ./.envs/.dev/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: apps_production_postgres
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - dev_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
      - dev_postgres_data_backups:/backups:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.dev/.postgres
    # ports must be set to use postgres container alone
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

If I run the django server locally(=not using docker-compose)with the command `python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.255:8000`, the client who is using the same wifi as me can access the API.
I got the 192.168.0.255 with the command `ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | cut -d\  -f6`(something I got after some googling).

If I run ifconfig, I get,

```
...
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
        ether a4:5e:60:f1:cb:5b
        inet6 fe80::85:51dd:e37a:5435%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x4
        inet 192.168.0.17 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
        nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
        media: autoselect
        status: active
...
```

Is there a way to run the docker-compose on my local wifi, so I can let the client developers who's on the same wifi to access the API?
Thanks.

---

(Edited)
The following does not seem to work neither :(

````
Thanks for the help. But this configuration does not seem to work.

```docker
...
services:
  django:
    ...
    networks:
      lan:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.0.10

  postgres:
    ...  
    networks:
      lan:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.0.11

networks:
  lan:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "192.168.0.0/24"
          gateway: "192.168.0.1"
````

Comment: What if the iOS developer runs the docker containers on his local machine and uses localhost to access the endpoints. Anytime there is a new push to your backend repo, they could just pull the latest commits. Would that be a stopgap solution?

Comment: @DruhinBala In fact, that's what we are doing at the moment. But unfortunately, this means the client developers can only use the emulators/simulators on the laptops to access the API, not the physical iPhone/Android phones, even it the device is connected to the laptops - or it there a way around this?

Comment: Found this on docker. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address . This looks like a promising solution where you would specify your IPv4 address (192.168.0.255) under the key `ipv4_address` in the custom network. It is listed under version 2 though. Hopefully it'll still work for version 3.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but it's not working neither. :(

Comment: did ios device access to your site with url 192.168.0.17:8000 or 192.168.0.255:8000?

Comment: @phapli indeed the ios device accessed my site with the latter (=192.168.0.255:8000)!

Comment: @Bossam: 192.168.0.255 is broadcast address, so it's not the right way. I expect you run server bind to 0.0.0.0 and from iOS device you should connect to your IP: 192.168.0.17

Comment: @phapli Indeed. I can confirm this works. Thanks! If you want to write that as an answer to this question, I'll mark it as answered :)

Comment: @Bossam did you use the above edited docker-compose.yml with networks file to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

192.168.0.255 is broadcast address, so it's not the right way to bind your server on this address.

I expect you run server bind to 0.0.0.0 and from iOS device you should connect to your IP: 192.168.0.17